# Could tensorflow optimize the each element's loss in a batch separately, instead of optimizing the whole average loss?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, loss

How could tensorflow optimize the batch's element losses individually instead of optimizing the batch loss?

When optimizing the loss for each batch, the common way is summing or taking the average of all the batch's element losses as the batch loss, and then optimizing this batch loss. In my case, I would like to optimize  each element's loss individually, instead of reducing them together as the batch loss.

For example, in the following codes.

```py
losses = tf.nn.nce_loss(<my batch inputs here>)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
optim = tf.nn.GradientDesentOptimizor(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(loss)
```

How could I skip `loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)` and minimize the tensor `losses` directly? (In this way, the mini-batch actually reduces to the situation that batch size is 1.)

I have feed the losses to minimize directly as:

```py
optim = tf.nn.GradientDesentOptimizor(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(losses) # instead of loss
```

I am not sure how will minimaziation work. When I use it to run in the session, the losses tend to explore to nan.

So is it possible to achieve the above aim in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between computation of gradients of `tf.reduce_mean(losses)` and gradients of `losses` is that for `losses` tensor you will get the SUM of gradients (the sum over gradients over each sample in a batch), while for `tf.reduce_mean(losses)` you will get the MEAN of the gradients (mean of gradients over the samples in a batch). That's why you start to get `NaN` values - the sum of gradients becomes a very large number as the size of the batch increases.

If you going to optimize a tensor loss instead of reduced mean loss you can get the exact equivalence by dividing your learning rate by the batch size.

To optimizer individually for each sample just feed one sample per batch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much! Your answer helps me understand the loss result. To optimize each sample individually, I have tried to feed one sample per batch. However, the speed is very slow, as I want to train a word2vec model by Tensorflow, which is a shadow network. When I increase the batch size, I find the result is bad at word similarity and analogy task. When I set the batch size as 1, the result is good, but the speed is very slow.

Comment: what is the embedding size that you use? In general, it is quite unusual to use 1 sample per batch in deep learning. What to you mean by "result is bad". How do you measure result?